# Presenter is null on injecting in activity

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-mvp

I am trying out dagger2 and want to inject a presenter into the activity, i searched the internet as to why the presenter is null but then i get different implementations of injecting an activity with several modules. Can someone please help me understand where i am going wrong when trying to create the dagger dependencies?

I have the following classes defined:

**ActivityComponent.class**

```
@PerActivity
@Component(modules = {ActivityModule.class}, dependencies = {AppComponent.class, GitHubComponent.class})
public interface ActivityComponent {
    void inject(AppCompatActivity activity);
}
```

**ActivityModule.class**

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {
    private AppCompatActivity activity;

    public ActivityModule(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    AppCompatActivity provideActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity public MainView provideMainView() {
        return new MainViewImpl(activity);
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    Context providesContext() {
        return activity;
    }

}
```

**AppModule.class**

```
@Singleton
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private final GitHubApp application;

    public AppModule(final GitHubApp application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    Application provideApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    public GitHubLog provideGithubLog() {
        return new GitHubLog();
    }
}
```

**GitHubModule.class**

```
@Module
public class GitHubModule {
    @Provides
    public MainInteractor provideMainInteractor() {
        return new MainInteractorImpl();
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    public MainPresenter provideMainPresenter(){
        return new MainPresenterImpl();
    }
}
```

**AppComponent.class**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(GitHubApp gitHubApp);

    void inject(GitHubLog gitHubLog);

    Application application();

    GitHubLog getGitHubLog();
}
```

**GithubComponent.class**

```
@Component(modules = {GitHubModule.class, AppModule.class})
public interface GitHubComponent {
    void inject(MainPresenterImpl presenter);
}
```

Inside the application class, i am created an `appcomponent` instance and also `githubcomponent` instance, that i use in the BaseActivity to create the `activitycomponent`.

And i inject the presenter inside `MainAcitivity that extends BaseActivity` and i get a null-pointer exception saying presenter is null.

Is my implementation incorrect? What could i be missing?

**EDIT:**
**GithubApp.class**

```
public class GitHubApp extends Application {
    public static GitHubApp INSTANCE;
    private AppComponent appComponent;
    private GitHubComponent gitHubComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        INSTANCE = this;
        getAppComponent().inject(this);
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        if (appComponent == null) {
            appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                    .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                    .gitHubModule(new GitHubModule())
                    .build();
        }

        return appComponent;
    }

    public GitHubComponent getGitHubComponent() {
        if (gitHubComponent == null) {
            gitHubComponent = DaggerGitHubComponent.builder()
                    .gitHubModule(new GitHubModule())
                    .build();
        }
        return gitHubComponent;
    }
}
```

How i inject the presenter into the activity is as under:
BaseActivity.class has a method that returns the activity component

```
return DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
            .appComponent(((GitHubApp)getApplication()).getAppComponent())
            .gitHubComponent(((GitHubApp)getApplication()).getGitHubComponent())
            .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
            .build();
```

In the MainActivity.class i use it like this:
before `super.onCreate()` is called, call `getActivityComponent().inject(this);`

@Inject
MainPresenter mainPresenter is the variable declaration

**EDIT2:**

Changes suggested by Chisko and Muhammad Babar work together, **as it is also required to change** the `inject(AppCompatActivity activity)` to `inject(MainActivity activity)`

Comment: Post your GitHubApp class

Comment: Your `ActivityComponent` should also define a method for the presenter. Something like `MainPresenter presenter();`

Comment: Components are supposed to reflect what Modules do in an abstract way. I know, sounds redundant.

Comment: Also, not sure how you are injecting the presenter, but I suggest to use the `@Inject` annotation both on the class member declaration and on the presenter's constructor

Comment: @MuhammadBabar, Chisko, i have updated the question with extra information

Comment: In your `ActivityComponent` replace `void inject(AppCompatActivity activity);` with `void inject(MainActivity activity)` and let me know if it works.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar, with your suggested changes, and also the code below, it works now .. thanks alot.. how do i share points between you and chisko ?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the comments, I think you are also missing additional setup:

**GitHubApp.java**

```
GitHubAppComponent component;

// call this inside onCreate()
private void setupComponent() {
    component = DaggerGitHubAppComponent.builder()
        .gitHubModule(new GitHubModule(this))
        .build();
}

public GitHubAppComponent getComponent() {
     return component;
}
```

As well as the activity component, which needs an abstract method on a `BaseActivity` you create:

**BaseActivity.java**

```
abstract void setupComponent(GitHubAppComponent appComponent);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    GitHubApp app = (GitHubApp) getApplication();
    GutHubAppComponent component = app.getComponent();
    setupComponent(component);
}
```

Then, your activities should also create the component:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void setupComponent(GitHubAppComponent appComponent) {
    ActivityComponent component = DaggerMainActivityComponent.builder()
        .gitHubAppComponent(appComponent)
        .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
        .build()
    component.inject(this);
}
```

I know it might appear like a pain in the a$$, but once you master Dagger you'll find out how easy and convenient it is.

Comment: But, activity module takes a this, that would point to the activity, then how would that be accepted in the GitHubApp.class ?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille corrected typo. That's what you meant right?

Comment: `// call this inside onCreate()
private void setupComponent() {
    component = DaggerGitHubAppComponent.builder()
        .activityModule(new AppModule(this))
        .build();
}

public GitHubAppComponent getComponent() {
     return component;
}` -> i was referring to this, i am sorry, i think i donot understand this part

Comment: I mean that you need to call `setupComponent()` inside `onCreate()` in your `GitHubApp` class

Comment: yes, so `setUpComponent`, has the method `activityModule(new AppModule(this))`, in the current code base, `AppModule` -> which is `Acitivity Module` accepts an `activity`, not an application class

Comment: There are two `setupComponent` methods, one that takes no arguments in your `Application` class, and the other that takes the application component as argument and that goes in your activities

Comment: yeah, so i added this code, and also changed from AppCompatActivity.class to MainActivity.class as per @MuhammadBabar it worked.

Comment: I guess the only missing part was the `inject()` call. But the architecture I explained here will make things easy for you. At least has done for me.

Comment: sure yes, thanks a lot.. how do i give points to both u and @MuhammadBabar in this case?

Comment: Well, I bothered to post an answer, and went a bit further than that :) I guess it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

In your *ActivityComponent* replace `void inject(AppCompatActivity activity)` with `void inject(MainActivity activity)`.